# How prove this inequality $\pi<\frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{x(1-x)}\le 4$

Tags: inequality

let $x\in (0,1)$ show that

> $$\pi<\dfrac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{x(1-x)}\le 4$$

I idea we know 
$$\sin{x}<x$$
and
$$x(1-x)\le\dfrac{1}{4}$$

But not usefull for this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $0<x<1$ one has
$${\sin(\pi x)\over x(1-x)}=4\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos t\ \cos(\sigma\>t\bigr)\ dt,$$ where $\sigma:=|2x-1|$.

Inspecting the right hand side one immediately sees that it is a decreasing function of $\sigma\in[0,1]$. Therefore it is maximal $(=4)$ when $\sigma=0$, i.e., $x={1\over2}$, and minimal $(=\pi)$ when $\sigma=1$, i.e., in the limit $x\to0$ or $x\to1$.

Answer (score 5):

You can also translate the variable and prove that 
$$ \frac{\pi}{4} \leq \frac{\cos(\pi x)}{1-4x^2} \leq 1 $$
for any $x\in [0,1/2]$, since the middle term is an even function. Now, since the Weiestrass product of the cosine function give us:
$$ \cos(\pi x) = \prod_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2n+1)^2}\right), $$
we have that the middle term is:
$$ f(x)=\frac{\cos(\pi x)}{1-4x^2} = \prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2n+1)^2}\right),$$
an infinite product of decreasing functions over $[0,1/2]$, hence a decreasing function, giving us:
$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\lim_{x\to 1/2} f(x)\leq f(x)\leq f(0)=1.$$

Answer (score 4):

$f(x)=\dfrac{\sin{\pi x}}{x(1-x)}$

note:$f(x)=f(1-x) \implies f(x) $ are symmetry $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$ when $x \in (0,1)$

now we prove $ f(x) $ will be mono increasing function when $x \in (0,\dfrac{1}{2}]$

$f'(x)= \dfrac{{\pi {x(1-x)}\cos(\pi x)-(1-2x)\sin(\pi x)}}{x^2(1-x)^2}$

$g(x)= \pi x(1-x)\cos(\pi x)-(1-2x)\sin(\pi x) $

$g'(x)=(2 - \pi^2 x(1- x) ) \sin(\pi x)=0$

$sin (\pi x)=0,x_{1}=0$,

$2 - \pi^2 x(1- x)=0, x_2=\dfrac{\pi - \sqrt{\pi^2-8} }{2 \pi}$

verify $g(0)=0 ,g(x_2)>0 \quad \text{(max point of} \ g(x))$

check bound $g(\dfrac{1}{2})=0 \implies g(x)\ge 0 \implies f'(x) >0$
$
f_{max}=f(\dfrac{1}{2})=4,f_{min}=f(0^+)=\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0+}}f(x)= \pi
$

QED.

Comment: Thank you,+1,and  I think this problem have nice methods.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$y=\frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{x(1-x)}$$
then
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{{\pi {x(1-x)}\cos(\pi x)-(1-2x)\sin(\pi x)}}{x^2(x-x^2)}$$
For the maximum/minimum values we need to know **x** that make
$${{\pi {x(1-x)}\cos(\pi x)-(1-2x)\sin(\pi x)}}=0$$
If$\quad$ $x=\frac{1}{2}$, we can easily find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$

If$\quad$ $x\not=\frac{1}{2}$,
$$x(1-x)\pi \cos(\pi x)=(1-2x)\sin{\pi x}$$
so
$$x^2(1-x)^2\pi^2 \cos^2(\pi x)=(1-2x)^2\sin^2{\pi x}$$
so
$${\dfrac{\pi^2 x^2(1-x)^2}{(1-2x)^2}}\cos^2(\pi x)=\sin^2{\pi x}=1-\cos^2(\pi x)$$
so
$${\cos^2(\pi x)}{\biggl[1+\dfrac{\pi^2 x^2(1-x)^2}{(1-2x)^2}\biggr]}=1$$

If we put 
$$g={\cos^2(\pi x)}{\biggl[1+\dfrac{\pi^2 x^2(1-x)^2}{(1-2x)^2}\biggr]-1}$$
then
$$g \gt0, \quad 0\lt x\lt \frac{1}{2}$$
$$g \lt0, \quad \frac {1}{2}\lt x\lt 1$$
$$g =0, \quad if\ x =0\ or\ 1$$
Because x $\in$ (0,1) only x=$\frac12$ will make $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$

and 
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} \gt 0 \quad if \quad 0\lt x \lt \frac12$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} \lt 0 \quad if \quad \frac12 \lt x \lt 1$$

because the denominator of $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$  $$x^2(x-x^2) \gt 0 \quad when \quad x\in (0,1)$$

so, y has its maximum at y($\frac12$)=4

and approaches its minimum value as x approaches to 0 or 1 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}y=\lim_{x \to 1}y = \pi
$$

Therefore $$\pi \lt \frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{x(1-x)} \le 4$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:  Let $x={1+u\over2}$ with $-1\le u\le1$.