# Investigate the convergence of $\sum a_n$, where $a_n =\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n \sin(\pi x)}{1-x} dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> **Problem:** Investigate the convergence of $\sum a_n$, where $a_n =\int_{0}^{1}  \frac{x^n \sin(\pi x)}{1-x} \, \mathrm{d}x$.

I'm thinking about changing $\frac{1}{1-x}$ to $\sum x^k$ and then exchange the integral and the sum but it came back to the original form. Or I just take the sum of $a_n$ switch the sum and integral since the integrand is nonnegative and measurable function. Then the integrand becomes $\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(1-x)^2}$,so I think the series should diverge.

Comment: Do you know the monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes. You mean here the partial sum of $a_n$ is increasing and we switch the sum and the limit?

Comment: I meant Beppo Levi's theorem for integrals.

Answer (score 6):

The series diverges. We have that
$$\sin\pi x\geq \pi x(1-x),\quad\forall x\in[0,1]$$
(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491463/how-prove-this-inequality-pi-frac-sin-pi-xx1-x-le-4)), so
$$a_n=\int_0^1\frac{x^n\sin \pi x}{1-x}dx\geq\int_0^1\pi x^{n+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{n+2}.$$
Hence $\sum a_n$ diverges by the comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

The monotone convergence theorem applies. Let $s_n$ denote the $n^{th}$ partial sum. Then$$ s_n=\int_0^1\dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^n x^i \sin(\pi x)}{1-x}dx=\int_0^1\dfrac{(1-x^{n+1})\sin(\pi x)}{(1-x)^2}dx$$Let's look at the integrand, $f_n(x)=\dfrac{(1-x^{n+1})\sin(\pi x)}{(1-x)^2}$. We know that $$f_n\to \dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{(1-x)^2}$$ pointwise, so you just need to show that this function is monotonic increasing, which is a simple calculation (that I can do out if you don't see it). Then by the monotone convergence theorem, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 \dfrac{(1-x^{n+1})\sin(\pi x)}{(1-x)^2}dx=\int_0^1\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{(1-x)^2}dx=\infty$$

Comment: thanks. This is just what I said. I just wasn't quite sure about this.